# Промежутки между столбцами в верстке таблицами Андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Сверстал таблицой кнопки 3x3.
Ниже код и принтскрин.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />


</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</TableRow> 
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</TableRow>   
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Почему между кнопками есть белое пространство, как будто явно указано свойство padding или margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего дело тут в дефолтных разделителях меж ячеками.

Поиграйтесь с атрибутами разделителей. Например:

```
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```